# How to strike a performance balance with documentDB collection for multiple tenants?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Say I have:

1. My data stored in documetDB's collection for all of my tenants. (i.e. multiple tenants).
2. I configured the collection in such a way that all of my data is distributed uniformly across all partitions.
3. But partitions are NOT by each tenant. I use some other scheme.
4. Because of this data for a particular tenant is distributed across multiple partitions.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this the right thing to do to maximum performance for both reading and writing data?
2. What if I want to query for a particular tenant? What are the caveats in writing this query?
3. Any other things that I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a sensible solution, where you avoid data skews and load-balance across partitions well. Since the query for a particular tenant needs to touch all partitions, please remember to set FeedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery to true (x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition in the REST API).

DocumentDB site also has an excellent article on partitioned collections and tips for choosing a partition key in general. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-partition-data/

Comment: But what are the cost implications for multi-partition queries versus single partition queries?

Comment: From per query RU cost's perspective, it makes little difference if you are querying multiple partitions or single partitions as the RU cost depends on how much data you retrieve, regardless of whether they are stored in a single partition or not. From performance cost's perspective, fanning out queries to multiple partitions actually load-balance well and should improve the perf of your queries. Finally, from the total cost's perspective, it is true that partitioned collections cost more than single partition collections because you are reserving more throughput with multiple partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid queries across partitions, they come with quite a cost (basically multiply index and parsing costs with number of partitions - defaults to 25). It's fairly easy to try out.

I would prefer a solution where one can query on a specific partition, typically partitioning by tenant ID.

Remember that with partitioned collections, there's stil limits on each partition (10K RU and 10GB) - I have written about it here http://blog.ulriksen.net/notes-on-documentdb-partitioning/

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your usage patterns as well as the variation in tenant size.

In general for multi-tenant systems, 99% of all operations are within a single tenant. If you make the tenantID your partition key, then those operations will only touch a single partition. This won't make a single operation any faster (latency) but could provide huge throughput gains when under load by multiple tenants. However, if you only have 5 tenants and 1 of them is 10x bigger than all the others, then using the tenantID as your key will lead to a very unbalanced system.

We use the tenantID as the partition key for our system and it seems to work well. We've talked about what we would do if it became very unbalanced and one idea is to make the partition key be the tenantID +  to split the large tenants up. We haven't had to do that yet though so we haven't worked out all of those details to know if that would actually be possible and performant, but we think it would work.